# How to pass a header and a parameter with a RSpec test controller

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to know how to test a controller (get verb) for a new end point.

```
Contains 
  header =  [authorization: token] 
  URL    =  id: 1

  EndPoint : https://tes.test.net.br/api/users/login/1
```

Example: Test Controller

```
 RSpec.describe Api::ApplicationController, type: :controller do

  let(:token) {'xx'}
  let(:url) { 'https://test.test.net.br' }
  let(:user_id) {1}

  describe 'GET login_with_token' do

    context 'with valid user and token' do
      it 'return the token data' do

        get "/login/{user_id}", {}, {'Authorization': token }   (doubt)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
        expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json"
        expect(response[:subdomain]).to eq('test')
        expect(response[:url]).to eq(url_portal)
        expect(response[:token]).not_to be_nil
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)". Don't use quoting unless you are referring to something someone else said. The code block should only contain code, not things like "Example: Test Controller". Misusing or failing to use proper formatting results in confusion which slows or discourages our attempts to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In controller specs you write `get :method_name` instead of the path. That's because controller specs don't actually create HTTP requests. Instead they create an instance of your controller and feed it a mocked request and then you are actually calling the method on the controller. Controller specs are depreciated.

What you  want is a request spec:

```
 # spec/requests/logins_spec.rb
 RSpec.describe 'Logins', type: :request do

  let(:token) {'xx'}
  let(:url) { 'https://test.test.net.br' }
  let(:user_id) {1}

  describe 'GET login_with_token' do
    context 'with valid user and token' do
      it 'return the token data' do
        get "/login/#{user_id}", params: {}, headers: {'Authorization': token }
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
        expect(response.content_type).to eq "application/json"
        expect(response[:subdomain]).to eq('test')
        expect(response[:url]).to eq(url_portal)
        expect(response[:token]).not_to be_nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: My question and how to call the get method to my end-point login. Since my end-point expects a token and an id

 End-Point : https://test.test.net.br/api/users/login/1
 Headers : Autorization  [ ' xxx ' ] // token
 Id : 1
 
 get "/login/{user_id}", {}, {'Authorization': token }   // ??

Comment: Why ask if you don't understand the answer?